# Google sheets Named ranges not consistent between sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two similar spreadsheets that share code in an apps script library.

I use named ranges to access the sheets from the code. 
In one spreadsheet the ranges are sheetname!range like this:[image]

and the other spreadsheet just uses range:[image]

I have tried copying both spreadsheets  and tried recreating ranges to match the other format but nothing seems to work.  I have looked for something that tells me that the spreadsheets are different versions but cant find anything that is different. I can make the code look for either format but.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy a worksheet in a spreadsheet with a Named Range, then Google Sheets has to do something, as you can't have two Named Ranges with the same name in the same spreadsheet. What it does is create new Ranges **with worksheet-level scope** of the form: `newworksheet!existingnamedrange`. So I think that probably explains how you got to where you are.

In terms of fixing it? You can just delete the `newworksheet!existingnamedrange` name and recreate `existingnamedrange`. As you can have the same name in different spreadsheets. Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: I also found that some references to other sheets would accept both formats but this particular sheet only the unqualified name was acceptable.